# Parse sending notifications in dashboard but Android device not receiving

Tags: java, android, xml, cordova, parse-platform

I've successfully created a Parse app and I'm using the application keys in my Android app implementation. I've followed all the steps here https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?onboard=#parse_push/android/existing *(registration required unfortunately, but it's an instant process)* and when I send a test push notification it is dispatched from the dashboard and is even received by a virtual device I'd set up as a control but nothing happens on a physical device. I thought it might be a socket issue so I alternated between wifi and 3G connections with no success

Here's the code I'm using:

Main:

```
package com.wetu.chronicle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class chronicle extends DroidGap
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());        
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxx",     "yyyyyyyyyyyy");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, chronicle.class);
    PushService.subscribe(this, "Newsfeed", chronicle.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.wetu.chronicle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.wetu.chronicle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">

        <activity android:name="chronicle" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.wetu.chronicle" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

I'm available to clarify any questions you might have and/or post additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most likely because your app isn't active in the background. A lot of my android apps have been struggling from this. A decent solution might be to make sure there is an alarm clock that wakes the app up. I've never dealt with parse though so this may not work, its worked for me in other scenarios though

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm looking into it right now. Will get back to you shortly.

Comment: A quick test for this is to open the app up exit it with the home button NOT the back button and then send the notification. If you dont get it then the problem is something else

Comment: It won't receive the notification even with the application open but this works in the emulator.